# How many databases to use for web system?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Does it matter how many databases I use in my web system? I am planning to have:

1. User information and related tables
2. Admin tables and all system tables
3. Reporting system
4. Audit logs of tables
5. User object tables like Photos, Videos, Comments
6. User API applications to read/write data.

Questions:

1. I am using MySQL and MagnoDB with cakephp. So if i implement above then i will use 6 databases in the system. Add backups so 2 of each then 12 databases total. Any advantage / disadvantage this way vs dumping all tables into 1 database? I assume thesedays with sites like yahoo, amazon, facebook, etc having hundreds or thousands of databases is the norm OR are these all powered by 1 database but having multiple instances?
2. For lookup tables: Do i duplicate them in each database or 1 copy in the admin database is good enough?
3. Also if i have multiple instance of the same DB do i need to name them like DB1, DB2, DB3 or can i call them anything?

We are developing a local reviews website so expect lots of users eventually.

Comment: This is a bad idea, and unnecessary too. And why are you planning to store `photos and videos` in a database? Why not use the file system?

Comment: No they are in the file system. Just the tables because there are 5 photo tables in my schema and each table will grow super big as photo sharing is a the core part of the site. So if we are adding millions of photos a day these tables will grow, so i thought is better to keep them seperate from the small tables for performance.

Comment: Storing media in the databases has a couple advantages. Security (access control to the media) is covered the same way as the rest of the data. And you get transactional consistency and backup/recovery at the db level. Studies have shown there to be neglible performance difference. Though I'd agree, movies, etc. would make more sense in a filesystem, but I wouldn't balk at storing images as a blob/binary in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single database. The problem with using multiple DBs include distributed queries (as pointed out already), plus overhead associated with each db server / instance, and general maintenance complexity.

What you want are ***tablespaces*** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-tablespace.html

Consider with dbs like Oracle, the overhead per instance is 300-500mb+. Not to mention a new set of processes and separate buffer caches. You want a single, unified buffer cache to make the most of your RAM.

Partitioning using a database as the partition unit isn't saving you much, but will make a giant headache. MySQL can handle huge amounts of data (terabytes), as long as you design your schemas well and tune the storage. And use separate tablespaces.

Moving your app, and backup / restore should be simple too.

The only reason I create separate DBs is if there are multiple customers involved, or the project requires it. But it is usually not required from a technical point of view.

Comment: So mixing high read/write tables with low read/write tables is fine? By high i mean the user tracking tables which log every movement of users on the site. I divided the databases purely for performance and the API database for security to seperate the user info from what data the API applications can read/write. Bad idea?

Comment: What you really want are _TABLESPACES_ not databases. Put your big logging tables in a separate tablespace (datafile). Though the security point is worth consideration. If you've some sensitive data, then no problem separating it, though I'd simply create a different user on the same db.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that has relative information should be in the same DB.
So if all the things you have mentioned have relative info you would need probably 3 DBs: dev, prod, backup.
If some of that info is not related to anything else, that it should be in the separate DB.
As a developer, I always create a new DB for each new unrelated project. Otherwise, you create / add new features to the existing DB.

Comment: What if 1 table is veru high read/write like an activity tracking table which is writting thouands of records a second vs the other tables which are low read/ write. Would you seperate that 1 table to a different DB just to prevent the other tables from performance issues?

Comment: you should not move a table to a separate DB just because of high read/write activity.

Answer (score 0):

disadvantages: trying to do joins across multiple database

Any area that you might need to relate to another area should all be in the same db.

Comment: Well, except reporting everything else depends on the other. I onlybroke it into 6 because of data volume. User objects are high read/write tables, user info are high read tables, admin tables are high writes for logging user info, API tables are to seperate user data from what applications can access.